# Error Report to SharePoint library

Tags: 2013, reporting-services, sql, sharepoint-library

I have configured the reporting service in native mode, add the SQL Server Reporting Services Service application, start the service, I created the data source for the report. But when I try to enter the report, it shows me a blank image. Anyone know that could be happening with my SharePoint report library

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a web application in sharepoint the web config makes the following reference by default:

In my case I was modifying some reference for my reports and had removed this default reference. Add this line and solve my issue

```
<add name="ReportViewerWebPart" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebPart.axd" type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.UI.WebParts.WebPartHttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.UI.WebParts, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
```